# Change base path for Laravel 5 using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a local working L 5.4 app and i want to deploy it online.

App was developed for using routes starting from base path ('/').

The problem is that the deployment url is http://example.com/admin/ and now all the links are broken due to this 'admin'.

I think .htaccess can solve this by setting the path to start from ('/') home path instead of edit all my routes and asset paths.

At the moment, i have created a new .htaccess in my app root folder to ignore the 'public' path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

i tried with some values here but all i get is "Forbidden Access" or HTTP ERROR 500.

The app works if i go to http://example.com/admin/public but assets are not working due to wrong paths.

Comment: Why not Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => ['role']], function () {.......});? With prefix

Comment: this would be the manual way which i want to avoid.. because i have to edit also the images paths, fonts, js files..and so on..